# How to add text and get input from the bottom of the terminal python curses?

Tags: python-3.x, python-curses

I am making an app in python curses and need to add text and get input from the bottom of the terminal. How do I do this?

I have tried using the getmaxyx function than then taking away 1 from the height then taking that away from the whole height from that, for people who may be confused:

Height - (height - 1)

and using that as the height arg for addstr but it threw an error saying that it returned ERR. please help!

Comment: `height-1-height=-1` or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Sorry I put it the wrong way round but it was the right way in my script

Comment: But this calculation is also trivial as it returns `+1`. Can you post a minimal working example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curses position is minimal at the top of the terminal and maximal at the bottom of the terminal so the y position at the bottom is `height - 1`.
Here is a minimal example:

```
import curses

def main(win):
    win.addstr(win.getmaxyx()[0] - 1, 0, 'Hello World!')
    win.refresh()
    win.getch()

curses.wrapper(main)
```